# How to put an onclick event for the item coming at the center of the canvas in android?

Tags: android, canvas, onclicklistener

I have implemented the below code to get the items in a circular scroll where in i have placed the items using a Canvas. And i get a layout like this.
[image: Circular scroll]
 I need to have an onclick listener on the item that comes to the center of the canvas and display a toast message which will contain the detail of the image. How do i determine the image that comes to the center and set an on click listener on it???? The onclick should be only on the center item and not the rest of the items.

Can anybody please help me with this???

Thanks in advance!!

```
public class CircleScrollListView extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnGestureListener {
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private Thread mThread;
private ArrayList<CircleDrawItem> datas = new ArrayList<CircleDrawItem>();
int[] playerDrawableResourceIds = new int[] { R.drawable.ronaldo,
        R.drawable.zindance, R.drawable.congvinh, R.drawable.huynhduc,
        R.drawable.gerrard, R.drawable.nagatomo, R.drawable.messi,
        R.drawable.minhphuong, R.drawable.neymar, R.drawable.ronaldo_beo,
        R.drawable.ronaldinho, R.drawable.xavi };
public int mCenterX;
public int mCenterY;
public int mRadius;
public double mStartAngleInRadian = Math.PI / 4;
private boolean isStop = false;

public CircleScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

private double calculateScrollAngle(float px1, float py1, float px2,
        float py2) {
    double radian1 = Math.atan2(py1, px1);
    double radian2 = Math.atan2(py2, px2);
    double diff = radian2 - radian1;
    return diff;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    Global.density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Global.dw = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    Global.dh = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    Global.dp = Global.density / 1.5f;

    // For circle data
    mCenterX = (int) (Global.dw / 2.0f);
    mCenterY = (int) (Global.dh);
//      mCenterX = (int) (Global.dp * 200);
//      mCenterY = (int) (Global.dh / 2.0f);
    mRadius = (int) (300 * Global.dp);
    mStartAngleInRadian = Math.PI / 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < playerDrawableResourceIds.length; i++) {
        CircleDrawItem circleDrawItem = new CircleDrawItem();
        circleDrawItem.mIconBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), playerDrawableResourceIds[i], 50, 50);
        circleDrawItem.mAngle = mStartAngleInRadian +i * Math.PI / 10;
        datas.add(circleDrawItem);
    }

    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isStop) {
                draw();
            }
        }
    });

    mThread.start();
}

protected void draw() {
    Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    if (canvas == null) {
        return;
    }
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {
        canvas.save();
        CircleDrawItem item = datas.get(i);
        double x = mCenterX + Math.cos(item.mAngle) * mRadius;
        double y = mCenterY - Math.sin(item.mAngle) * mRadius;
        canvas.drawBitmap(item.mIconBitmap,
                (int) x - item.mIconBitmap.getWidth() / 2, (int) y
                        - item.mIconBitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
    canvas.restore();
    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    isStop = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    float tpx = e1.getY();
    float tpy = e2.getX();
    float disx = (int) distanceY;
    float disy = (int) distanceX;
    double scrollAngle = calculateScrollAngle(tpx, tpy, tpx + disx, tpy
            + disy);
    for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {
        datas.get(i).mAngle += scrollAngle;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go ; I don't have that much experience with Java, but I should be able to help you on how to do it.

Create a little square, in your code, with a posX, a posY, a width and a height. Try to get your images coordinates too. Now compare them both. Is an image at the same position than your little square ?

Do you understand the reasoning behind this ?